# How can I use an "alias" for the destination directory when copying?

Tags: bash, alias, cp

I frequently edit startup files such as my `.bashrc` file
Then I copy them to another direction such as `~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1`

Is there any way I can `cp` such files to the above location with something like an alias?
I currently have an alias to cd to it with `alias n='cd ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1'`

I'd like something that would handle any file I pass into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh yes, you can!

1. Open your `~/.bash_aliases` file and type the following to the end of the file(create a new `~/.bash_aliases` if it doesn't exist):

   ```
   alias mycp='cp ~/.bashrc ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1'
   ```

   This will create an alias `mycp`(you can give a different name for `mycp`)which will copy your `~/.bashrc` file to the desired location.
2. You could create a shell variable which contains the long path and then use the variable in place of the long path. For example, in your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   export fav_path=/usr/share/help/nl/gnome-help/figures/
   ```

   and `source ~/.bashrc` and then use

   ```
   cp ~/.bashrc "$fav_path"
   ```

Remember to use the `"` for paths containing spaces.

Comment: +1 That's useful.  I am looking for something more generic.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Added an alternative method, couldn't think of a more generic method :/

Comment: Those both work.  In the end I ended up using an alias to do all of what I really needed, i.e. `alias bup='cp ~/.bashrc ~/Dropnot/setups; cd ~/Dropnot/setups; git add .bashrc; git commit -m".bashrc update"; git push origin master;'` !

Comment: Then I also made a bdown command to do `alias bdown='cp ~/Dropnot/setups/.bashrc ~; . ~/.bashrc'`

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `cp` (on Linux is answer is most likely yes), you can use the `-t` option:

```
alias fcp="cp -t ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1"
```

Doing `fcp somefile` will always put the file in the `~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1` directory. Multiple arguments will work as well (eg `fcp somefile otherfile1` will both go to `~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1`)

If GNU `cp` is not available, you can always use a function:

```
fcp () {
  cp "$@" ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
alias c='cp ~/.bashrc ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1'
```

I would suggest to instead *move* the file there and use a symbolic link to avoid the copy altogether:

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1/
ln -s ~/Dropnot/level1/setups/bash1/ ~/.bashrc
```

I've been using this for my [dotfiles](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/19862a70e13e586b6b39ba391044eecec95636db/Makefile#L3-L26) for years, and it's been very helpful in keeping a backup.

Comment: I believe you the OP meant the `~/.bashrc` file. So you'll always need to provide the `~/.bashrc` file. Simply `.bashrc` will try to locate `.bashrc` in the current directory where the OP is.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to type out the long path that way and use something shorter, similar to the way aliases help.